# What's the best practice (from SEO perspective) to remove pages from your website

Tags: seo, google, search

Removing products from Shopify resulted in 404 when google kept redirecting traffic to indexed links which resulted in gradual drop in the site ranking as well as organic traffic.

Right now we're unchecking the product from all the sales channels (website, FB, google, ebay...) which results in 404 when it appears on the Google search results.

When considering adding redirects to these products: some items we simply want to stop selling and we can redirect to the collection or similar products, and some are seasonal and we are not sure where to redirect it to.

What's the best practice to remove a product from the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's useful to use the rule of thumb here that what's best for your visitors is also, more likely than not, best for SEO.

Redirecting a discontinued product to a similar product or even a similar category is probably fine and could help you retain link-juice - as long as the destination page is very relevant.

For seasonal products, I would strongly consider leaving the page up year-round, but with a custom out-of-stock notice on the off season. That way the page will always resolve and its search engine presence will be ever persistent.